# catkin init command not found

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i entered "catkin init". i get error "catkin command not found"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248606/catkin-init-command-not-found/) by [abhay2302](https://answers.ros.org/users/28289/abhay2302/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2016-11-22**:
Please don't post images of text...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your screenshot:

> ```
> $ catkin init
> ```

```
catkin: command not found
```

The `catkin` command is provided by [catkin_tools](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io), which is not installed by default in a `ros-$distro-*` install (`desktop` or `desktop-full` fi). The default would be `catkin_init_workspace`.

Note that I don't know which version (`catkin_tools` or plain Catkin) is recommended in the Ariac documentation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1